# Finder is extremely slow and keeps crashing, 1tb ssd

Tags: finder, macos, crash, indexing

Finder keeps crashing on my computer.

If I push a key to search any folder, it crashes.

I’ve re-indexed my ssd, but it’s still happening

mid-2012 MacBook Pro, macOS Sierra, 16gb ram

Also, I have a second, internal 500gb hdd

Comment: Is the second HDD indexed?  Is it functioning properly? Can you disconnect it to see if things speed up?

Comment: The 500gb hdd (running windows) is indexed (using NTFS for Mac, and it doesn’t speed things up when disconnected. Also, it is functioning properly

Comment: time to isolate your SSD.  Create a macOS install on a USB flash drive (just for testing) and boot from that.  See if the issue goes away.  You may also want to run [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.

Comment: How will I access finder from the installer (unless you’re accessing it from the import profile button in terminal)?

Comment: I have an installer thumb drive ready for when you tell me

Comment: You're going to do a complete install of macOS on a blank USB drive.  It's for testing.  It's not as fast as an SSD, but it will help you diagnose the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90270/discussion-between-sam-and-allan).

Comment: @Allan, I’ve tried to access my ssd from multiple people’s computers in the past, and on all of them finder was slow and crashed

Comment: It's not clear how you "accessed your ssd from multiple computers" but that should at least clue you into the SSD being faulty.  That said, the macOS install on USB is to test your *system* as well.  At this point do a reinstall.  If that doesn't solve it, your SSD is failing.

Comment: I meant I accessed my system from multiple different computers, and via firewire and target mode. I did a reinstall yesterday (because of this: https://imgur.com/gallery/BRdA6Z2), and I have SSDReporter checking my ssd, which is apparantly at 100% health

Comment: Going to run AHT